# knockoutjs binding different API objects

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, dojo

I am working some APIs with javascritp like dojo toolkit, google maps API, Arcgis API,...
I want to bind objects to view side via knockout. But APIs has own specific objects. For example:

Some API:

```
var map = new Map();

var layer = new BaseMapLayer();
map.add(layer)

var pointLayer = new PointLayer("name", {visible: true});
map.add(pointLayer);
```

API developer gives me a PointLayer object. And I can set some options in constructor like visible to show on map. We don't know what does it in background. This is not important.

`PointLayer` gives us two methods to change visibility.

```
pointLayer.Show();
pointLayer.Hide();
```

But we can not use `pointLayer.visibile = false or true`

Like this stuation, I want to practically bind objects with knockout.

```
var viewModel = {
     layers:[pointLayer]
} 
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

how can I bind layer visibility to a checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should extend or wrap the `PointLayer` object so that the extension/wrapper has a [writeable computed observable](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computedObservables.html#writeable-computed-observables) along these lines:

```
var _isVisible = ko.observable(false);

pointLayer.isVisible = ko.computed({
    write: function(val) {
        _isVisible(val);
        if (!!val) { pointLayer.Show(); }
        else { pointLayer.Hide(); }
    },
    read: _isVisible;
});
```

The `_isVisible` observable is kinda like a private backing field for the `isVisible` "property". It keeps the actual state. (If the pointLayer object *does* have a *readonly* property for visibility it's better to just use that one.).

The `isVisible` computed observable will do two things:

- **Write**: show or hide the layer depending on the new value.
- **Read**: just return the current state of the layer.

This observable can be bound to a checkbox normally.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're building a Table of Contents or something to turn layers on and off with a checkbox, you should be able to bind a visible property of each object in an array to a checkbox.

You could build your view model constructor to create an object with observables for the properties you want to work with for each type, then add each object to the layers array. Then you could bind a checkbox to the visible observable of each layer object in your observable array.

```
var viewModel = function ( inputLayerArray ) {
    var that = this;
    var layerArray = inputLayerArray || [];
    this.layers = ko.observableArray();
    if ( layerArray.length > 0 ) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach( layerArray, function ( item ) {
            if (item instanceof PointLayer) {
                that.layers.push( {
                    name: item.name,
                    visible: item.visible
                } );
            }
        } );
    }

    function getLayerByName( layerName ) {
        return ko.utils.arrayFilter( layerArray, function ( item ) {
            return item.name === layerName;
        } );
    }

    function hideLayer( layerName ) {
        var layers = getLayerByName( layerName );
        if ( layers.length > 0 ) {
            layers[0].HideLayer();
        }
    }

    function showLayer( layerName ) {
        var layers = getLayerByName( layerName );
        if ( layers.length > 0 ) {
            layers[0].ShowLayer();
        }
    }

    this.toggleLayer = function( data ) {
        if ( data.visible( ) === true ) {
            showLayer( data.name ); 
        } else {
            hideLayer( data.name );
        }
    };
};
```

To use other object types, just add code to create another object with the observables you need. Using common names inside your view model can mask the differences between different objects and different APIs.